# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton - android

Tags: android

I want to run my activity I got this error :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_diary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_diary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my class extended a `AppCompatActivity` class.

my style :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/felipecsl/m2repository/master' }
    //  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    ...
```

Comment: Activity or AppCompatActivity which one are u using?

Comment: "my class extended a `AppCompatActivity` class."

Comment: try to move `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Use the latest design support library, that might help you in resolving this

Comment: @S.M_Emamian did you tried using CoordinatorLayout instead of RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 2):

Try this
1 . update design support library and appCompat library using sdk manager which installs the latest versions.
2. Use Appcompat theme.
3. Extend your Activity from AppCompatActivity instead of Activity.
4. Try to keep the version of both libraries same

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

5. After all these clean your project and run .

Answer (score 1):

This one work for me finally. Change this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'    
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

Into this :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move 
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
from to FloatingActionButton to RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from xml layout in Floating Button

```
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Change or modify code in  the Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.java.user.sample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

> Add the necessary dependency below this code and rebuild it ,run the
>   projects

Answer (score 0):

make the android app compat and android studio design in the same version is works for me..